# Mysql update field text by appending another field text from the same row

Tags: mysql, append, field

I have a table called `words` with, among other fields, `base` and `inflection`

I would like to delete the field `inflection` by having it appended to `base` with a hyphen (`-`) when `inflection` is not empty.

How... should I do that? I really don't want to mess with my table ^^'

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE words SET base = concat(base,"-",inflection)
WHERE inflection <> "" OR inflection IS NOT NULL;
```